# Styling html body inline

Tags: html, css, height, inline

I need to add this:

```
html, body{
height: 100%;
}
```

However, I am currently stuck in a CMS where I can only edit under the BODY tag, which means that I am not able to add anything to the header, adjust the stylesheet or similar. My only way to add this is  inline past the body tag. I can also execute PHP within this space if that would in any way solve this.

Am I in an impossible situation or is there a solution?

Comment: Also, I do hope you realize that adding a style tag within the body tag is perfectly valid and will run just as well as in the head.

Comment: @TheZ That is only true of scoped style tags in an HTML5 doctype. Outside of HTML5, contrary to specs, some modern browsers will let you get away with it, but it isn't standard behavior so you don't want to rely on it.

Comment: @Chris Really? I've never seen it explicitly stated as illegal in the W3C documentation for `<style>` tags (heavily implied perhaps?) but that's definitely true with `<link>` tags.

Comment: Yep! Check out the spec page here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#edef-STYLE Bear in mind, this is HTML4 we're talking. The statement isn't as explicitly worded as it is in the `LINK` spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-LINK)... "HTML permits any number of STYLE elements in the HEAD section of a document." for `STYLE` vs "Unlike A, it may only appear in the HEAD section of a document" for `LINK`. With the forthcoming release of HTML5 and the scoped style tag, browser vendors are not very strict on implementation, that's why it may work, though it "shouldn't"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could output a javascript string with PHP that can adjust the styles:

```
print '<script>document.body.style.height = '100%'; document.body.parentNode.style.height = '100%';</script>';
```

That said, if you aren't concerned about HTML validation and/or are using an HTML5 doctype, you *can* simply add a normal style tag anywhere. If you need to output this using PHP, just put it into a string (as I did with the above javascript):

```
print '<style type="text/css">html, body{ height: 100%; }</style>';
```

You may also want to look in to scoped style tags, a new addition to HTML5: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-style-element.html#attr-style-scoped

**Documentation**

- PHP `print` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php
- Javascript `element.style` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.style
- Scoped style sheets - http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-style-element.html#attr-style-scoped

Comment: Where do I add this? Do I execute it in a script tag? Php? please provide more information, I am a learning coder...

Comment: This is a PHP `print` statement. You stated that "I can also execute PHP within this space if that would in any way solve this.", so you would use this code there. If you can directly add content to the body outside of PHP, then just use the `<script>` tag and everything in it, don't use the `print` statement.

Comment: I tried your code but it returned with **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER** can you please review your code if it is correct?

Comment: Never mind, I added it directly as you suggested and it worked, cheers!

Comment: Yeah I was going to, there is a time limit that was keeping me from it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript to change the properties of those tags after the fact.

If you're already (or you want to try) using jquery,  it's pretty easy.  Just run this script:

```
$("html").css("height","100%");
```

If you don't want to use jquery, then the way you do it for most browser is the following:

```
document.body.style.height = "100%";
```

OR

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.height = "100%";
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, although my question was resolved by the time that you did. I have upvoted it though.

Comment: I'm glad you included the vanilla javascript on here, but honestly, adding jQuery **only to do this one thing** is like cutting a cake with a chainsaw... overkill in the extreme

Comment: @Chris - totally agree - I start there because most CMS's or decently size projects use it anyway.

Comment: That's true, and fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this will work, style tag can be added anywhere:

```
<style>
html, body{
height: 100%;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to javascript(which you do), you can just add:

```
<script>
  var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  body.style.background='#000';
</script>
```

Comment: So in my case, would it be **body.style.height='100%';**?

Comment: he wants to change the hieght not the background color